# Start multiple vagrant boxes in parallel via Makefile

Tags: zsh, make, parallelism

I have three vagrant boxes I usually need simultaneously so I created a Makefile to start them all at once. Well, one after the other actually.

The Makefile looks like this basically:

```
up:
        cd box1 && vagrant up;
        cd box2 && vagrant up;
        cd box3 && vagrant up;
```

They are starting one after the other, which means it takes a lot of time. But a lot of that time is just waiting, there is not a lot happening. So I figured I want to start them in parallel to reduce the needed time.

Simply putting an `&` after `vagrant up` doesn't work. Neither if I put it between `$()`, `""` or ``` `` ```.

What do I need to do to make these boxes start in parallel?

I use `zsh` as shell BTW.

Comment: `make -j N` starts multiple jobs concurrently, that is probably what you should use. Or invoke `parallel`. You can also make a shell script that starts them all (using `&`), but that defeats the purpose of the Makefile.

Comment: @Anthon can you give an example of how to use `make -j N`? The documentation is not clear for me and I cannot find good examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer this question myself now. The Makefile should look like this:

```
.PHONY: up box1_up box2_up box3_up

up: box1_up box2_up box3_up

box1_up:
    cd box1 && vagrant up;

box2_up:
    cd box2 && vagrant up;

box3_up:
    cd box3 && vagrant up;
```

And invoke like this: `make -j3 up`